# Sequence $(u_n)$ such that

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Consider the following operator $H=\partial_{x^2}+x^2$ acting on $L^2(\Bbb{R})$. It's well known that the spectrum of $H$ is $\Bbb{R}$. So by weyl's criteron there exists $(u_n)\in D(H)$ such that

$||u_n||=1$ and $H(u_n)\to 0$ in $L^2(\Bbb{R})$.

Can I find explicitly such sequence?

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial_{x^{2}}$?

Comment: It means $\partial_{x^{2}}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.